# Laravel: Handle unique on Update

Tags: php, laravel

I'm using the validation for the employee records during an update. There are some fields which should be unique. But during an update of the employee records, the validation for the unique field is being done. I have researched and tried out the solution as well. 
But I'm getting this error:

> Error Code : 904 Error Message : ORA-00904: "ID": invalid identifier
>   Position : 71 Statement : select count(*) as aggregate from
>   "EMPLOYEES" where " EMAIL" = :p0 and "ID" <> :p1 Bindings :
>   [ad@sdfdsf.com,3336] (SQL: select count(*) as aggregate from
>   "EMPLOYEES" where " EMAIL" = ad@sdfdsf.com and "ID" <> 3336)

*Here is my attempt for the solution:*

```
public function update(Request $request, int $employee_id) {

    $this->validate ( $request, [
            'first_name' => "required|max:220|regex:/[a-z]/",
            'middle_name' => "max:120",
            'last_name' => "required|max:220|regex:/[a-z]/",
            'email' => "required|unique:employees, email, $employee_id|regex:/[a-zA-Z0-9._%+-]+@[a-zA-Z0-9.-]+\.[a-zA-Z]{2,6}/",
            'home_phone' => "unique:employees,home_phone, $employee_id|numeric|regex:/^[09][0-9]{8,9}$/",
            'mobile' => "unique:employees,mobile, $employee_id|numeric|regex:/(9)[0-9]{9}/",
            'job_id' => 'required',
            'department_id' => 'required',
            'group_id' => 'required',
            'node' => 'required',
            'branch' => 'required',
            'username' => "required|unique:employees,username, $employee_id|regex:/[A-Za-z0-9][.][A-Za-z0-9]/",
            'exchange_username' => "required|unique:employees,exchange_username, $employee_id|regex:/[A-Za-z0-9][.][A-Za-z0-9]/",
            'extension' => "unique:employees,extension, $employee_id|numeric|regex:/[0-9]{4}/",
    ] );

    Employee::where ('employee_id', $employee_id )->update ( $request->only ( [ 
            'first_name',
            'middle_name',
            'last_name',
            'email',
            'address',
            'home_phone',
            'mobile',
            'job_id',
            'department_id',
            'group_id',
            'branch',
            'node', 
            'name',
            'username',
            'type',
            'exchange_username',
            'toggle_ivr_access',
            'extension',
            'attributed_team',
            'cable_team_id',
            'disable',

    ] ) );
    Session::flash ( 'message', 'The Employee is Successfully Updated.' );
    return redirect ()->route ( 'employees.index' );
}
```

Comment: Check your column names. You must enter valid column name. When you didn't this error showing up mostly.

Comment: I have checked it. The column names are correct.

Comment: which line is `71` ?

Comment: Please review my updated part below. I have posted the error part because of which the error occurs.

Answer (score 0):

> [Forcing A Unique Rule To Ignore A Given ID:](https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/validation)
>
> Sometimes, you may wish to ignore a given ID during the unique check.
>   For example, consider an "update profile" screen that includes the
>   user's name, e-mail address, and location. Of course, you will want to
>   verify that the e-mail address is unique. However, if the user only
>   changes the name field and not the e-mail field, you do not want a
>   validation error to be thrown because the user is already the owner of
>   the e-mail address.
>
> To instruct the validator to ignore the user's ID, we'll use the Rule
>   class to fluently define the rule. In this example, we'll also specify
>   the validation rules as an array instead of using the | character to
>   delimit the rules:

```
use Illuminate\Validation\Rule;

Validator::make($data, [
    'email' => [
        'required',
        Rule::unique('users')->ignore($user->id),
    ],
]);
```

Comment: I haven't use the Validator class of the Laravel so this process doesn't work for me. I have gone through the Laravel documentation and use them but couldn't get the expected solution. Please review the attempt that I have posted above.

Comment: @DixonChaudhary in your case `Validator::make($data,` can be replaced with `$this->validate ( $request,`, but you do need the rule object, and validation rules can also be defined as `array` instead of a `string` seperated by `|`

Answer (score 0):

I figured out the mistake and successfully find out the solution. Here is the working solution in case anyone is facing the similar problem. I had to pass the employee_id of the single user whereas I was passing the employee_id of the multiple users.

```
public function update(Request $request, int $employee_id) {
        $this->validate ( $request, [
                'first_name' => "required|max:220|regex:/[a-z]/",
                'middle_name' => "max:120",
                'last_name' => "required|max:220|regex:/[a-z]/",
                'email' => "required|unique:employees,email,".$employee_id.',employee_id|regex:/[a-zA-Z0-9._%+-]+@[a-zA-Z0-9.-]+\.[a-zA-Z]{2,6}/',
                'home_phone' => "unique:employees,home_phone,$employee_id,employee_id|numeric",
                'mobile' => "required|unique:employees,mobile,$employee_id,employee_id|numeric",
                'job_id' => 'required',
                'department_id' => 'required',
                'group_id' => 'required',
                'node' => 'required',
                'branch' => 'required',
                'username' => "required|unique:employees,username,".$employee_id.',employee_id|regex:/[A-Za-z0-9][.][A-Za-z0-9]/',
                'exchange_username' => "required|unique:employees,exchange_username,".$employee_id.',employee_id|regex:/[A-Za-z0-9][.][A-Za-z0-9]/',
                'extension' => "required|unique:employees,mobile,$employee_id,employee_id|numeric|regex:/[0-9]{4}/",    
        ] );
        Employee::where ('employee_id', $employee_id )->update ( $request->only ( [ 
                'first_name',
                'middle_name',
                'last_name',
                'email',
                'address',
                'home_phone',
                'mobile',
                'job_id',
                'department_id',
                'group_id',
                'branch',
                'node', 
                'name',
                'username',
                'type',
                'exchange_username',
                'toggle_ivr_access',
                'extension',
                'attributed_team',
                'cable_team_id',
                'disable',
        ] ) );
        Session::flash ( 'message', 'The Employee is Successfully Updated.' );
        return redirect ()->route ( 'employees.index' );
    }
```